# Check if 4 of the same colors are in the same collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 4 colliders which should check if there are 4 of the same colors are in that collider.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/2e63ce683c7ee023124a7065013f6cda.png]

They all have the same tag (Tile).

The white blocks are the colliders, but in this case, only the top-left, the top-right, the bottom-left and the bottom-right colliders are important. They should check if they are colliding with a match of four colors, doesn't matter which color.

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/aa918f7d02b3b385f96b05e328906dff.png]

How do I make it so that these colliders detect that?

Comment: You need to post what you have tried so far. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I know, but that didn't really make sense and it didn't work so I don't see the point of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

FireSquid's solution should work.

Here's a proposition if it doesn't.

Instead of making a collider check where the white colliders must through collision detect the colors of the objects around them, you could make a set of references in the code instead.

This would likely only be efficient for a small and fixed amount of colliders, at least the way I present it, but it would work.

Simply put.

- Each white collider should have a reference variable to the bigger coloured colliders.
- You can then have it go through those references checking their colour, this should be acquirable material of the Renderer component of each object.

EDIT: Elaborated solution.

```
public List<Renderer> _Renderers; //here you must add the cubes manually in the inspector.

Color _ColorToMatch; //this will automatically be set in the code.

public bool CheckIfColorsMatch() {
    CheckIfValidVariables();
    for (int i = 0; i < _Renderers.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            _ColorToMatch = _Renderers[i].material.color;
        }
        if (!_Renderers[i].material.color.Equals(_ColorToMatch))
        { 
            //If colors don't match, return false.
            return false;
        }
    } 
    //If all colors match, return true.
    return true;
}

void CheckIfValidVariables() {
    if (_Renderers == null)
    {
        //Renderer list no initiated.
        Debug.Log("Renderer list no initiated.");
        return;
    }

    if (_Renderers.Count == 0)
    {
        //No renderers set as reference.
        Debug.Log("No renderers set as reference.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I don't really understand what you mean, but no problem. I think I found a way. I only need to know how I can check if a list contains 4 objects by name. I tried this, but this gives an error because you can only check it with 1 object: https://pastebin.com/d6FYwQVW

Comment: I mean that you can make public variables or serialized private variables, so that they are visible in the Inspector GUI in Unity when you add the script to an object.

You can then drag the colour cubes from the Hierachy to the Inspector GUI variable fields, connecting them in that matter.

I edited my answer above and added a code example.

Comment: I added all the cubes to the list, but it always returns True (sorry for late response)

Comment: If you used the method I posted above, the fault might be in this line:

if (!_Renderers[i].material.color.Equals(_ColorToMatch))

So in how the code compares the colours.

Try use this instead.

if (_Renderers[i].material.color != _ColorToMatch)

If that doesn't work, please post your code.

Comment: This also returns True. I noticed that if I run Debug.Log `(_Renderers [i].material.color);` it always returns `RGBA(1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000)` I also changed Render to SpriteRenderer in the list, but that also didn't work. I also tried to change the list from SpriteRenderer to Color and then assign 4x4 colors in the inspector, https://i.gyazo.com/b8fa707358bf446ad29d36df18c481e5.png the same as the tiles. However, this always returned False. I have the same code as in your script. `CheckIfColorsMatch()` is called when you press a button which rotates the tiles.

Comment: I removed the `.material` after  `(_Renderers [i]`, because the color is assigned via the sprite renderer component. Now it doesnt return `RGBA(1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000)` anymore, it returns the right colors I think, but it still keeps returning True.

Comment: RGBA(1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000) is a white colour.
Whether you use SpriteRenderer or Renderer, I don't think that should matter when it comes to the colour of the material.

You could try make a Debug.Log("Color: "+_Renderers[i].material.color); to see what it prints if you wish to know the RGBA values as float values.

Comment: See my last comment. I already fixed the RGBA, but it still remains True.

Comment: Have you got any idea?

Comment: Am a bit busy atm., just came home from work. does StackOverflow allow private communication? This comment section is getting a bit lengthy.

Comment: I don't think that there's a private communication on stackoverflow.

Comment: Give all your cubes a name in the inspector, for example "White", "Red", "Blue" and so on. This name can then be printed if as you say you have a list of cubes to go through, so try print them for example with Debug.Log(name); to the console.

That way you will get the correct colours in, which can be compared. You would only be comparing strings this way, but it's an alternative if you can't seem to get the colour comparison working.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest way would be to use [Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll.html) to get an array of the [Collider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html)s. You can get the gameobjects from the colliders and then check their materials to see what color they are.